# How to set a starting state in cirq?

Tags: programming, cirq

I'm learning how to use the cirq library. Every time I set up a circuit the starting state of the qubits is $|0000..0\rangle$. Is there any way to make the starting state different? I'm thinking of somehow giving as input some `np.array (vector)` to the circuit so that the system initializes with such state. I know I could build a circuit to prepare the state I want but I would like a shorter way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cirq distinguishes between "running" a circuit, which is generally supposed to act like hardware would (e.g. only getting samples), and "simulating" a circuit, which has more freedom.

Most "simulate" methods, like `cirq.Simulator().simulate(...)` have a parameter `initial_state` which can either be a computational basis state (specified as an integer e.g. `initial_state=0b000111000`) or a state vector (specified as a numpy array e.g. `initial_state=np.array([0.5, -0.5, 0.5j, 0.5])`).

For "run" methods, like `cirq.Simulator().run(...)`, there is no way to specify the initial state because that's how it works in hardware. If you want a specific state, you have to make it with gates.

Comment: Then how can we "force" the qubit in specific state ?