# Producing $|ghz\rangle\langle ghz|$ State in Cirq

Tags: programming, quantum-state, cirq, ghz-state

I could manage to produce 3 qubit ghz state in Cirq. But I don't know how I can produce $|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|$  in Cirq
Here is my code for 3 qubit ghz state
Can you help me please for improving my code from $|GHZ\rangle$ to $|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|$:

```
n = 3
qubits = cirq.LineQubit.range ( n )

def circuit ():
  circuit = cirq.Circuit ()
  circuit.append (cirq.H(qubits[0]))
  for i in range (n-1):
    circuit.append ( cirq.CNOT ( qubits [i] , qubits [i+1]) )
  circuit.append (cirq.measure (* qubits , key ='x') )
  print (circuit)
  return circuit

def simulation (circuit):
  simulator = cirq.Simulator()
  results = simulator.run ( circuit , repetitions = 200)
  counts = cirq.plot_state_histogram (results)

def main():
  simulation (circuit())
if __name__ == "__main__ ":
   main ()
```

Comment: A density matrix for a state $|\psi\rangle$ is $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. In your case, $|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|$ is $|GHZ\rangle$ run on  [cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One more thing is that: I actually want that: p.|GHZ><GHZ|+(1-p)*rho
The rho itself could also be expressed in terms of some other things though. So it will look like 
rho = q . rho_{1,2} + r . rho_{2,3} + s . rho{1,3} + (1-q-r-s) . rho_separable
and each of these rho_{i,j} states will be bipartite entangled. How can I do that?

Comment: If you can define the unitary matrix for each of these terms, then you can create a class that will represent your noisy evolution, using the mixture protocol in Cirq. https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/noise.html#cirq.mixture-and-def-mixture Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Do you want a numpy array storing the matrix |GHZ><GHZ|? That's `cirq.final_density_matrix(your_circuit)` (well.. if you omit the measurement it is). Or do you want a representation of this state to feed into other parts of cirq? Which parts?

Comment: Dear Balint Pato thanks you very much for your answer! Can you at least show me how I can write rho ( rho = q . rho_{1,2} + r . rho_{2,3} + s . rho{1,3} + (1-q-r-s) . rho_separable) part with Cirq? Maybe after completing this part I can just use density matrix @BalintPato

Comment: Dear Craig Gidney, Thank you very much for your answer. Before cirq.final_state_density_matrix(the circuit), I need to create rho and p. So I need representation of this state to feed into other parts of cirq After that I can maybe use the function (cirq.final_density_matrix) @CraigGidney

Comment: @quest You create your states by creating a circuit that prepares them and then simulating that circuit. The state you want will be result of the simulation.

Comment: You can also create states like this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/how-to-set-a-starting-state-in-cirq?rq=1

Comment: I added an answer to this question in your follow up question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14288/bit-flip-seperable-state-and-several-question-about-cirq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can produce the GHZ state, I will skip the corresponding code and just use that QuantumCircuit object to build a density matrix $|GHZ><GHZ|$.

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
DM=DensityMatrix.from_instruction(circuit)
# here circuit denotes the circuit that contains your GHZ state.
```

Or there is another way to do so(not recommended, just for reference).

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators import StateFn
psi=StateFn(circuit)# produce the state vector
DM=(psi@~psi).eval()# state ket tensor state bra =density matrix
# When calling StateFn function, the quantum circuit must not contain classical register
```

But note that the density matrix produced by the latter method is not admitted by qiskit, because the DensityMatrix object in qiskit has two attributes(the matrix itself and its dimension).